# Bluebird is not resolving the promise correctly

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I am trying to convert the froogaloop javascript api into a promisified API calls,

here is my code

```
FroogaLoopPlayer.promisify = (player) => {
  //player.on = player.addEvent;

  _.each(functionNames, (fn) => {
    _.each(fn, (value, key) => {
      player[key] = () => {
        var data;
        return new Bluebird(resolve => {
          player.api(value, (d) => {
            console.log(d);
            data = d;
            console.log(data);
          });

          resolve(data);
        });
      };
    });
  });

  return player;
};
```

the problem is, the data i get is always undefined. What I could be doing wrong?. I have already tried this, which i suppose is the correct way.

```
return new Bluebird(resolve => {
  player.api(value, resolve);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your `resolve()` after the call to the asynchronous function (where `data` [is `undefined` of course](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572)), but in the callback:

```
return new Bluebird(resolve => {
  player.api(value, (d) => {
    resolve(d);
  });
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  return data;
});
```

You can also use just `player.api(value, resolve)`.

Comment: Maybe `d` is nothing either? How do you call the function?

Comment: like this ```player.getCurrentTime().then((time) => {
            console.log($scope.dip);
            $scope.dip.time = time;
          });```, and no, when i do ```console.log(d)``` .. it returns me a value.

Comment: also, when i do how you tell me to do it, console.log does not get executed. the second argument disappears somewhere)

Comment: So the callback does get executed, but `time` is undefined?

Comment: when i do, ```resolve(d)```, like you said, the callback does not get executed.

Comment: Does the `(d) => {resolve(d);}` callback get executed at all?

Comment: no. .. when i do ```(d) => { console.log(d); resolve(d); }```, i don't get anything in console. only when i resolve the promise outside the function call, we get something.

Comment: i also tried doing resolve(player.api()); .. when doesn't get me anything.

Comment: Well then you have to blame `player.api` not calling its callback, not the promises. Is it an asynchronous method at all? Do you have a link to its docs?

Comment: this is the froogaloop sdk link https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/blob/master/javascript/froogaloop.js and these are the docs https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Comment: @mouse: It appears that `void` "methods" don't call their callback back - as they don't "return" anything, and they're not even really asynchronous.

Comment: thankyou @Bergi .. it appears the problem is with froogaloop library.